# Bad request while getting WSDL with SoapClient through proxy in PHP

Tags: php, soap, proxy, wsdl

I have two servers : one is used for development and can access to the WEB easily but another one for production which can access to the WEB only using a proxy.

I would like to call a SOAP WEB service from my production server.

So following is the code (the URLs are fake):

```
$url = 'https://www.webservice.com/soap.php';
$wsdl = 'https://www.webservice.com/soap.php?wsdl';

$client = new SoapClient
(
        $wsdl,
        array
        (
                'location'      => $url,
                'proxy_host'    => 'www.myproxy.com',
                'proxy_port'    => 8080,
        )
);


$namespace = 'urn:mynamespace';
$header = array
(
        'header1' => 'H1',
        'header2' => 'H2',
        'header3' => 'H3',
);

$client->__setSoapHeaders(new SoapHeader($namespace, 'myHeader', $header));

$params = array
(
        'param1' => 'val1',
        'param2' => 'val2',
        'param3' => 'val3',
);

$result = $client->method($params);
```

I run it from my development server and I get the expected result.
Now I run it from my production server and I get :

```
PHP Warning:  SoapClient::SoapClient(https://www.webservice.com/soap.php?wsdl): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
PHP Warning:  SoapClient::SoapClient(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "https://www.webservice.com/soap.php?wsdl" in /home/benji/test.php on line 20
PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://www.webservice.com/soap.php?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://www.webservice.com/soap.php?wsdl"
```

When I wget the wsdl from the production server, it's working:

```
$ https_proxy=www.myproxy.com wget https://www.webservice.com/soap.php?wsdl
--2013-02-22 10:57:40--  https://www.webservice.com/soap.php?wsdl
Resolving www.myproxy.com... 10.0.0.125
Connecting to www.myproxy.com|10.0.0.125|:8080... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/xml]
Saving to: `soap.php?wsdl'

    [ <=>                                                                                                                                            ] 9 010       --.-K/s   in 0,009s  

2013-02-22 10:57:40 (980 KB/s) - `soap.php?wsdl' saved [9010]
```

Comment: is it real url ? https://www.webservice.com/soap.php?wsdl

Comment: no it's not... The URL of the WEB service and of the proxy are fake

Comment: have you tried to ping or wget the URL from the production server? maybe the problem is you are unnable to see the url from the production server.

Comment: I'm using PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze14

Answer (score 7):

The following solution solved the described problem for me:

- create a new stream context where you also specify your proxy information
- for the stream context set option [SNI_enabled](http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php) to false
- pass the stream context as new parameter in the options array to the soapclient

  ```
  $context = stream_context_create(
  array(
      'ssl' => array(
          'SNI_enabled' => false
      ),
      'http' => array(
          'proxy' => 'tcp://yourproxy.com:9999'
      )
  )
  );
  $soapOptions = array(
      'stream_context' => $context
  );
  $soapClient = new SoapClient( 'wsdl.path', $soapOptions );
  ```

Comment: I don't understand why, but this just helped me.